How do I write a json file using the fs module after I have packaged my app using electron builder
I am working on a project which involves writing a json file in the app directory, in a file called
'data' and the name of the json file is 'data.json'. Here is my code:

const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu} = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');

const dataDir = path.join(__dirname, 'data');
const accountsFile = path.join(dataDir, 'data.json');

async function createDirectoryAndFile() {
    try {
        // Check if the directory exists
        const dirExists = await fs.promises.access(dataDir).then(() => true).catch(() => false);

        if (!dirExists) {
            // Directory doesn't exist, create it
            await fs.promises.mkdir(dataDir);
            
            // Create the file inside the directory
            await fs.promises.writeFile(accountsFile, '[]');
            
            console.log('Directory and file created successfully.');
        } else {
            console.log('Directory already exists.');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
}

// Call the function
createDirectoryAndFile();




Now this works perfectly fine during development, but after I package it using electron-builder
for windows, target nsis, it does not seem to work. Moreover, it gives I get this error when I run the Wizard setup:
enter image description here

Replace  __dirname  by  app.getPath('userData') , Use { recursive: true } in mkdir  and Call the function when the app is ready app.whenReady().then(createDirectoryAndFile);

To expand on what @khribi-wessim said, when you build and install an Electron app, __dirname usually refers to a directory inside the app's ASAR archive. This is a read-only filesystem, so you won't be able to create files and folders in there. Now, app.getPath('userData') seems like a reasonable alternative. This directory be used to store user-scoped data that should survive restarts of the application or system. But what kind of data are you planning to store in data.json?
